# File path errors in eclipse? (Java Spring)

Tags: java, spring, input, io

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/ExportHour.xls");
```

I have a file in the src/main/resources folder of my Java Spring project.
I am attempting to create an inputstream in one of my Controllers, however I always get a file not found exception. When I change the path location to point specifically to the file on my machine, it works fine.

Any way I can make it so the file can be found within the java project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with spring [ClassPathResource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html).

```
InputStream inp = new ClassPathResource("ExportHour.xls").getInputStream();
```

That is because the resources folder in maven is put in your jar file directly i.e. the ExportHours.xls file is put inside your jar in the root directory.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you *could* just change the working directory of your process - it's not where you think it is, I suspect. For example, I suggest you write

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources/ExportHour.xls");
```

and then log `file.getAbsolutePath()`, to see what exact file it's using.

However, you should almost certainly *not* be using a `FileInputStream` anyway. It would be better to use something like:

```
InputStream inp = Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("/ExportHour.xls");
```

... for some class `Foo` which has a classloader which includes the resources you need.

(Or possibly `/resources/ExportHour.xls"`, depending on your build structure.)

That way even when you've built all of this into a jar file, you'll still be able to open the resource.

Comment: +1 In the middle of writing the answer and then @Jon Skeet puts me into shame with another flawless answer